# Transaction rather than query postgres log analyzer?

Tags: postgresql, logging, database-performance, analysis

In order to optimize performance for a multi-threaded application that is using an underlying Postgresql database I need the help of a tool that can read postgresql logs and provide reporting on which transaction blocks another and transaction statistics.

Such a tool could, for example, identify common patterns of blocking transactions based on actual application usage. This could indirectly suggest different handling/grouping of queries that could quickly lead to better performance.

A well known tool is pgbadger but it seems its main 'unit' is queries rather than transactions. While delays/blocks etc are reported for queries I saw no reference to transactions or what transaction had the lock at the time (or what query for that matter).

At the same time, postgresql logging is able to report BEGIN/COMMIT with Virtual transaction IDs so such a tool seems feasible.

I have also seen some methods for real-time lock monitoring however I would need post-processing logs (not just real-time monitoring which would probably only work if you happen to catch such a lock).

Is there a tool, preferably free, that performs post analysis to transactions rather than queries and can help in understanding application locking performance?

Comment: If you always acquire locks in alphabetical order  you'll avoid deadlocks. is this a single-user application?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this is a multi-threaded multi-user application. Deadlocks may or may not be related, I dont think they are in my case (none is detected by 1 sec deadlock timeout). My question is mainly about blocking due to programming of the logic in relation to actual usage - and the existence of a logging analysis tool that can help. Thanks!